# Ошибки при резервном копировании Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows, резервное-копирование, windows-server-2012, raid

Есть контроллер домена Windows 2012 R2, системная дисковая система RAID1 (2хSSD) на встроенном контроллере. Из дополнительных ролей стоит только DHCP.
Настроена полная ежедневная локальная архивация на отдельный физический HDD диск. Практически каждая операция архивации завешается с ошибками:

> Один из компонентов системы является несогласованным в теневой копии,
>   созданной для архивации. Сведения об ошибке: Повторяющаяся ошибка
>   средства записи. Эта ошибка вероятно будет возникать снова при
>   повторении попытки архивации.

Запуск утилиты Intel Rapid с проверкой и исправлением ошибки исправляет, но на следующий день процедура архивации снова завершается с теми же ошибками.

Что это может быть? Менять диски или что-то не так настроено.

UPDATE: vssadmin.exe list writers показывает, что NTDS поврежден, в eventlog ругается на повреждения журналов NTDS. Вывод и последующий ввод DC проблему не решил.

**Проблема решилась** заменой RAID1 (2хSSD) на RAID1 (2хHDD).

Comment: Что говорит `vssadmin.exe list writers`?

Comment: @Akina
vssadmin.exe list writers показывает, что NTDS поврежден, в eventlog ругается на повреждения журналов NTDS, восстановление через ntdsutil особого результата не дали.

Comment: Всё это - важная информация. Добавляйте её в текст вопроса, с цитатами...